# How do I remove the tab order number from all components in delphi?

Tags: delphi, cnpack

I am always forgetting where to disable the component tab order number in Delphi. Could you kindly explain to me where do I need to do it?

[image: Component tab order number]

I have searched everywhere, or at least I think I did. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I recall this to be a feature of CNPack. Check related tool buttons / menu items.

Answer (score 6):

Untoggle the following item in the IDE's toolbar:

```
CnPack -> Tab Orders -> Display Tab Order
```

[image: Picture of the CnPack toolbar item allowing to toggle/untoggle the tab orders visibility]

Answer (score 2):

Above the form designer is a CNPack toolbar with a toggle button to show/hide the Tab order:

[image: Form designer with CNPack toolbar]